# Keras CNTK stops working when I train the model

Tags: keras, cntk

I have changed keras backend to "cntk" in keras.json file.

When I execute my python file [execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD4sn.png)

it stops working.
[stop-working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGFD2.png)

But when I use tensorflow/theano is working normally.
Why?

----------update

[image-pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMJkM.png)

When pycharm Found images(image-pycharm) ,it stop suddenly.
And then I try to use cmd to execute my python file.
The result is "The system stop working"

Comment: Is there an error that it gives when it stops working?

Comment: No,I get nothing. It just show the system stop working